# Mysql check if a value exists in which column

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has two columns - city and country. Given a string 'X', how to know the column name which has the value 'X'?

For example, if 'X' is new york, query should return column name City and if 'X' is USA, query should return column name Country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN city = 'X' 
            THEN 'City' 
        ELSE 'Country' 
    END column_Value 
FROM [table_Name] 
WHERE city = 'X' OR country = 'X';
```

You can make use of the above query.

Answer (score 0):

`select count(*) from tableName where city = "X" or country = "x"`

If 0 is returned then it doesn't exist.

To check for column then:

`select count(*) from tableName where city = "X"`
If 0 is returned then it doesn't exist in city

`select count(*) from tableName where country = "X"`
If 0 is returned then it doesn't exist in country

Comment: Updated question. Please look again. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: then specify that in the question.